# Django startswith vs endswith performance on MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, indexing, django-models, django-queryset

Lets say I have the following model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
```

So I would have objects in the database like

```
Person.objects.create(name='alex white')
Person.objects.create(name='alex chen')
Person.objects.create(name='tony white')
```

I could then subsequently query for all users whose first name is `alex` or last name is `white` by doing the following

```
all_alex = Person.objects.filter(name__startswith='alex')
all_white = Person.objects.filter(name__endswith='white')
```

I do not know how Django implements this under the hood, but I am going to guess it is with a SQL `LIKE 'alex%'` or `LIKE '%white'`

However, since according to [MySQL index documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-btree-hash.html), since the primary key index can only be used (e.g. as opposed to a full table scan) if `%` appears on the end of the `LIKE` query.

**Does that mean that, as the database grows, `startswith` will be viable - whereas `endswith` will not be since it will resort to full table scans?**

Am I correct or did I go wrong somewhere? Keep in mind these are not facts but just my deductions that I made from general assumptions - hence why I am asking for confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want **`AND`** -- that is only `Alex White` and not `Alex Chen` or `Tony White`, ...

Even better (assuming there is an index starting with `name`) is

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE name LIKE 'Alex%White'
```

If Django can't generate that, then it is getting in the way of efficient use of MySQL.

This construct will scan all the names starting with `alex`, further filtering on the rest of the expression.

If you do want **`OR` (and 3 names)**, then you are stuck with

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE ( name LIKE 'Alex%'
         OR name LIKE '%White' )
```

And there is no choice but to scan all the `names`.

In some situations, perhaps this one, **`FULLTEXT`** would be better:

```
FULLTEXT(name)  -- This index is needed for the following:

SELECT ...
    WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('Alex White' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  -- for OR

SELECT ...
    WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('+Alex +White' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  -- for AND
```

(Again, I don't know the Django capabilities.)

Comment: Actually my original question was quite simply just "does startswith performs better than endswith" . In other words, I am asking whether or not only startswith uses an index. I never asked for any and or or statements. I really dont understand how both answers came about like this

Comment: Startswith is fast; endswith is slow.

Comment: OK, in rereading your question, I see what you meant.  I was mislead by your use of "or" outside of SQL, plus Lajos's answer using "and".  Hopefully, you have learned more than you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

```
select *
from foo
where bar like 'text1%' and bar like '%text2'
```

is not necessarily optimal. This could be an improvement:

```
select *
from (select *
      from foo
      where foo.bar like 'text1%') t
where t.bar like '%text2'
```

You need to make measurements to check whether this is better. If it is, the cause is thatin the inner query you use an index, while in the outer query you not use an index, but the set is prefiltered by the first query, therefore you have a much smaller set to query.

I am not at all a Django expert, so my answer might be wrong, but I believe chaining your `filter` would be helpful if `filter` actually executes the query. If that is the case, then you can use the optimization described above. If `filter` just prepares a query and chaining filters will result in a single query different from the one above, then I recommend using hand-written MySQL. However, if you do not have performance issues yet, then it is premature to optimize it, since you cannot really test the amount of performance you gained.

Comment: @knbk, since we do not posess the source-code of MySQL, it is difficult to tell how will it react without having the actual query on the actual database table. My answer forces MySQL to use the index even if it ends up not using it. It is not querying a whole table, just the results. If the number of results happen to be very large, then the approach might fail, so it is advisable to check whether there will probably not too many records. Texts starting with 'a' might be frequent, but texts starting with 'abcdef' are probably rare.

Comment: @knbk, there are several problems preventing me from benchmarking. I do not have the user's data, nor the scheme. If we had them, then we could decide whether this approach is feasible in op's specific case. My answer is merely showing an idea of forcing things to work well. This idea should be applied only in the case when MySQL does not happend things in the right way. MySQL's code is open source, yes. By not owning it I mean I do not know what is inside it. And I do not know because I do not check it.

Comment: @knbk, thank you for the constructive criticism, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I disagree with the need for the subquery.  The optimizer will see `LIKE text1%` and perform a 'range' query.  For each such row, it will check the other clause, which cannot be optimized due to the leading wild card.  In newer versions, you also get the bonus of 'ICP', as indicated by "Using index condition" in the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Actually my original question was quite simply just "does startswith performs better than endswith" . In other words, I am asking whether or not only startswith uses an index. I never asked for any and or or statements. I really dont understand how both answers came about like this